# unable to read file data, getting request payload as {} with 400 error code

Tags: reactjs

getting 400 status code, can anyone explain why
I've searched everywhere but I can't seem to get it working

```
    handleBulkUpload() {
        alert("Bulk upload submitted")
        const file = this.state.csvFile;
        console.log("csv file: ", file)

        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', file)


        post("/uploadOCFile", data)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log({response})
            }).catch((error) => console.error({error}))

    }
```

```
               <div className='attribute-selector'>
                    <h3>Bulk Upload</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>You can upload a file to bulk upload </p>
                        <div>
                            <label style={{ marginRight: "2px", paddingTop: "8px", paddingBottom: "40px"  }}> File: </label>
                            <input id="csvUpload" name="file" type="file" onChange={this.handleFileChange} />
                        </div>
                        <label style={{ color: "red" }} >{this.state.errorMsg}</label>
                        <div className='submit-button'>
                            <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary' onClick={this.handleBulkUpload} disabled={this.isBulkUploadDisabled()}>
                                Upload
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I'm getting 400 code, can you please how to append file so that contents will be displayed in front end, I'm seeing 400 code in console and request payload as {}

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/oc")
public class OCFileUploadController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadOCFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public FileUploadStatus uploadOCFileContent(final @RequestParam MultipartFile file) {
        log.info("OCFileUploadController : file: ", file);

        FileUploadStatus status = null;

        try {
            // validation
            // service call

            status = new FileUploadStatus();
            status.setMessage("File uploaded successfully");
            status.setStatus(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status = new FileUploadStatus();
            status.setMessage("File upload failed");
            status.setStatus(false);
        }
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: Do you can share some information about you api (/uploadOCFile)?

Comment: @KaiW, added the backend file